# Dictionaries or Dual Arrays

Tags: java

For the fun of it I am writing a Character class to help me learn what I need to know for video game development. I am also using this to help learn Java.

I want to store a characters stats as a Dictionary(key value pairs), but I'm unclear on how this is done in Java. The other option I am thinking of is to use two arrays(one for stat names, the other for stat values).

What is the best way to store key value pairs in Java?

Comment: See what's all available: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is probably the [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) object you're looking for, although there are others that may be more suitable for your needs.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key", "value");
String value = map.get("key");
```

Comment: Is there a Map collection type that will keep the order of the pairs?

Comment: You can use a LinkedHashMap if you need to preserve the insertion order: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html